# moving frame with maple

Tags: differential-geometry, maple, cartan-geometry

I have already ask this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210861/moving-frame-with-maple), but since it concerns as mathematics than computer science, I ask it here too.

I would like to make a classical computation using maple. I would like define an abstract moving frame (e_1,e_2), then

1) get the dual frame omega_1, omega_2 (always abstract) omega_i(e_j)=delta_i^j

2) define omega_12 such that d omega_1= omega_12 wedge omega_2

3) define Gauss curvature K such that d omega_12=K omega_1\wedge omega_2

4) Finally I would like to get an abstract formula for \overline{K} the curvature of the a new frame (\overline{e}_1,\overline{e}_2)=e^f (e_1,e_2) , where f is a abstract function, with respect to  K and f.

I should use the package Differential geometry but even I don't succeed to define the frame. The exmpale in the description of the library is

> DGsetup([x,y,z,w],M):

Example 1.
Define a 3-dimensional subspace of vectors by the span of S and compute a simpler base for this subspace relative to the coordinate basis T for the tangent space of M.

> S1:=evalDG([D_x−D_y,D_x+D_y,D_x+D_y+D_w])

But S1 is an explicit frame I want to define an abstract one as I can do for functions.
For instance if I want an abstract Liebnitz rule,

> diff(f(x)*g(x), x);

```
           / d      \             / d      \
           |--- f(x)| g(x) + f(x) |--- g(x)|
           \ dx     /             \ dx     /
```

Here I have tryied the following:

> with(DifferentialGeometry);
>   DGsetup([x, y], M);
>   S1 := evalDG([e1, e2]);
>   M > B1 := DGbasis(S1);
>   Error, (in DifferentialGeometry:-DGbasis) expected 1st argument to be a list of biforms, forms, vectors tensors, matrices, vectors. Received [e1, e2]

---

EDIT:

Here is what I have start to do with Atlas. As you see, it doesn't use the symmetries of the Lie derivative. And I don't know how to make my 4)

[image: screen shot]

Comment: @ Paul, I believe that I know how to implement this with Maple directly and will try to provide an answer later tonight or this afternoon.  If you like working with moving frames and prefer the Cartan approach to Differential and Riemannian geometry, then I recommend that you take a look at an add on package for Maple and Mathematica called Atlas.  I find it to be far more efficient and intuitive for Cartan style calculations and I now almost exclusively use Atlas in Maple (as opposed to Maple's built in package) when making these calculations:  http://www.digi-area.com/Maple/atlas/

Comment: @THW, Atlas looks like what I was looking for. I am gonna to have a serious look at it.

Comment: @THW, no idea of what looks wrong in my screen shot?

Comment: @ Paul, Are you willing to assume that your frame/co-frame is orthonormal?

Comment: orthonormal with respect to a given metric $g$ but not with respect to the euclidean one a priori.

Answer (score 1):

@Paul, I must confess that it is not clear to me exactly what you are looking for in regards to 4.), but I think that what you can do with Atlas combined with a little exterior algebra works quite nicely.  (I have attached a screen shot of my Maple file below and I am having some issues with some of the simplifications as well.  I seem to remember having these problems before, but of late I have been using Mathematica and a newer version of Atlas.  The attached screen shot is from what I believe to be the original version of Atlas and Maple 15 so it is possibly outdated.  I apologize for any confusion that this causes.)

**Notation:** In keeping with the notation of Atlas, I use $\iota$ for the interior product of a vector field with a differential form.

**Key Theorems:**

- For any differential 1-form $\omega$, $\mathrm{d}\omega$ is defined by
  $$
  \mathrm{d}\omega\left(X, Y\right) = X\left(\omega\left(Y\right)\right) - Y\left(\omega\left(Y\right)\right) - \omega\left( \left[ X, Y\right]\right),
  $$
  where $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary vector fields.
- For any differential form $\omega$ and any vector field $X$, we have the following relationship between the interior product, the Lie derivative, and the exterior derivative
  $$ \iota_{X} \mathrm{d}\omega = \mathcal{L}_{X} \omega - \mathrm{d}\left(\iota_{X} \omega\right).$$
- Suppose that $\omega^{i}$ constitute a local coframe with dual frame $E_{i}$.  Then 
  $$\mathcal{L}_{E_{i}}\omega^{j} = A_{ik}^{j}\omega^{k} = - \omega^{j}\left(\left[E_{i}, E_{k}\right]\right)\omega^{k} = -C_{ik}^{j}\omega^{k},$$
  where $C_{ik}^{j}$ are the structure functions of the frame $E_{i}$, i.e., $\left[E_{i}, E_{k}\right] = C_{ik}^{j}E_{j}$.

Now, assuming that we are on a two dimensional manifold and that $\omega^{1}$ and $\omega^{2}$ form an orthonormal coframe for a metric tensor $g$, i.e., $g = \omega^{1} \otimes \omega^{1} + \omega^{2} \otimes \omega^{2}$, one calculates $\omega^{1}_{2}$ to be

$$
\omega^{1}_{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\,\iota_{{E_{{2}}}} \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{1}} \right)  \right) +
\,\iota_{{E_{{1}}}} \left( \iota_{{E_{{2}}}} \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{1}} \right)  \right)  \right) \omega^{{1}}-\,\iota_{{E_{{1}}}}
 \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{2}} \right)  \right) + \,\iota_{{E_{{1}}}}
 \left( \iota_{{E_{{2}}}} \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{2}} \right) 
 \right)  \right) \omega^{{2}}\right).
$$

Going term-by-term through $\omega^{1}_{2}$ we have

- $\iota_{{E_{{2}}}} \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{1}} \right)  \right)= \mathcal{L}_{E_{2}}\omega^{1} = -C_{2k}^{1}\omega^{k} = C_{12}^{1}\omega^{1}$
- $\iota_{{E_{{1}}}} \left( \iota_{{E_{{2}}}} \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{1}} \right)  \right)  \right) \omega^{{1}} = -\omega^{1}\left(\left[E_{2}, E_{1}\right]\right)\omega^{1}=  C_{12}^{1}\omega^{1}$
- $-\,\iota_{{E_{{1}}}}
   \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{2}} \right)  \right) = -\mathcal{L}_{E_{1}}\omega^{2} = \omega^{2}\left(\left[E_{1}, E_{k}\right]\right)\omega^{k} = C_{12}^{2}\omega^{2}$
- $\iota_{{E_{{1}}}}
   \left( \iota_{{E_{{2}}}} \left( \mathrm{d} \left( \omega^{{2}} \right) 
   \right)  \right) \omega^{{2}} = -\omega^{2}\left(\left[E_{2}, E_{1}\right]\right) \omega^{2} = C_{12}^{2}\omega^{2}.$

We thus have
$$
\omega^{1}_{2} = C_{12}^{1}\omega^{1} + C_{12}^{2}\omega^{2},
$$
and one can see that 
$$\mathrm{d}\omega^{1} = -\omega^{1}_{2} \wedge \omega^2 = -C_{12}^{1}\omega^{1} \wedge \omega^{2}.$$
Furthermore, we have 
$$\mathrm{d}\omega^{2}  = -\omega^{2}_{1} \wedge \omega^1 = \omega^{1}_{2}\wedge \omega^{1} = C_{12}^{2} \omega^{2}\wedge \omega^{1} = -C_{12}^{2}\omega^{1}\wedge\omega^{2}
$$

To calculate the curvature, we now have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}\omega^{1}_{2} &= \mathrm{d}\left(C_{12}^{1}\omega^{1} + C_{12}^{2}\omega^{2}\right)\\
&= \mathrm{d}C_{12}^{1}\wedge \omega^{1} + C_{12}^{1}\mathrm{d}\omega^{1} +\mathrm{d}C_{12}^{2}\wedge\omega^{2} +C_{12}^{2}\mathrm{d}\omega^{2}\\
&= \mathrm{d}C_{12}^{1}\wedge \omega^{1} + C_{12}^{1}\left(-C_{12}^{1}\omega^{1}\wedge \omega^{2}\right) +\mathrm{d}C_{12}^{2}\wedge\omega^{2} +C_{12}^{2}\left(-C_{12}^{2}\omega^{1}\wedge\omega^{2}\right)\\
&= \left(E_{1}C_{12}^{1}\omega^{1} + E_{2}C_{12}^{2}\omega^{2}\right) \wedge \omega^{1} - \left(C_{12}^{1}\right)^2\omega^{1}\wedge \omega^{2} +\left(E_{1}C_{12}^{2}\omega^{1} +E_{2}C_{12}^{2}\omega^{2}\right)\wedge\omega^{2} -\left(C_{12}^{2}\right)^2\omega^{1}\wedge\omega^{2}\\
&=E_{2}C_{12}^{2}\,\omega^{2} \wedge \omega^{1} -\left(C_{12}^{1}\right)^2\left(\omega^{1}\wedge \omega^{2}\right) + E_{1}C_{12}^{2}\omega^{1}\wedge\omega^{2}  -\left(C_{12}^{2}\right)^2\omega^{1}\wedge\omega^{2}\\
&= \underbrace{\left(-E_{2}C_{12}^{2} - \left(C_{12}^{1}\right)^2 + E_{1}C_{12}^{2} - \left(C_{12}^{2}\right)^2\right)}_{K}\omega^{1}\wedge \omega^{2}
\end{align*}

Note:  In the Maple file created with Atlas, I wrote $\omega^{1}_{2}$ as $$\omega^{1}_{2} = \phi = A \omega^{1} + B \omega^{2}, $$
where $A= C_{12}^{1}$ and $B = C_{12}^{2}$.  I also did not spell out explicitly where I used the three key theorems in the substitutions.  Let me know if you have any additional questions and/or spot any errors.

I initially thought that there would be a more direct solution using Atlas, but this is the best that I see at the moment.

---

[image]